# OSGI dependencies of Sling Starter as Maven Dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, sling

Is there a maven artefact that declares all the OSGI bundles exported by the [Apache Sling Starter](https://github.com/apache/sling-org-apache-sling-starter) which could e.g. be included with scope `import` into an artefact to be deployed on Sling to automatically have the right versions of all those Sling bundles when compiling the artefact? Or is there a tool to generate such a thing?

(Usually you include many many dependencies like org.apache.sling.api, org.apache.sling.annotations, org.apache.sling.servlets.get... as dependencies into a Sling project. When moving to a new version of Sling Starter, it's quite a pain to pick the right versions from the http://localhost:9090/system/console/bundles display. I'm looking for a nice way to do that.)

Comment: That's a good question, and we don't have something like this right now. What _might_ works is adding the slingstart-maven-plugin to your project and add a dependency to the sling starter. Then the classpath should be populated, at least when building using the command line. AFAIR this does not work in Eclipse though

Comment: @RobertMunteanu Thank you, yes, but that means I've always got everything and its grandmother in the classpath. :-)  Well, for now I created something one can put as scope include in the dependencyManagement - see https://github.com/ist-dresden/composum-meta. and created an improvement issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SLING-8664 about that.

Comment: Yes it does pollute the classpath quite a bit ... Thanks for the issue report